# How can I ensure that aWIX installer only upgrades from a certain version and otherwise aborts the installation with an error message?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have an installer based on Windows Installer XML.
Within the XML i have follwoing upgrade section

```
<Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="0.0.1" IncludeMinimum="yes" Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)" Property="OLDERVERSIONBEINGUPGRADED" />
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)" OnlyDetect="yes" Property="NEWERVERSIONDETECTED" />
</Upgrade>
<Condition Message="!(loc.NewerVersionFound)">NOT NEWERVERSIONDETECTED OR Installed</Condition>
```

Now i want that an upgrade is only performed if the installed version is at least 2.1.0
Otherwise a message should be thrown (as if a newer version is found) and the installation
should be aborted.

I thought i have to set the minimum value to 2.1.0 within the UpgradeVersion but that doesn't work.

How can i archive that?